DFT on images: quantitative measurements on magnitude spectrum
I was wondering whether I can use Discrete Fourier Transformation to quantify aspects of complexity and variability in images. My goal is to compare patterns found in images, such as color patterns of animals, in a quantitative but generally applicable fashion. Specifically, I was thinking  of doing stats on these different regions of the magnitude spectrum (image credit):
                                         
In addition I could just extract moments and percentiles of the entire magnitude spectrum - for example, a large high-frequency count might be associated with many transitions, i.e., many patches of different pixel intensity, and a high standard deviation might be associated with large differences between patches.
So, in light of the above, would something like the code snipped below make sense, or am I misinterpreting the magnitude spectrum?
import cv2
import numpy as np
import phenopype as pp

def compute_DFT_stats(image, channel="gray", size=600):
    
    ## slice and resize 
    img2d = core.preprocessing.decompose_image(image, channel)
    img2d = cv2.resize(img2d, (size, size))
    
    # apply the DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform)
    dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img2d), flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
    dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
    magnitude_spectrum = 20 * np.log(cv2.magnitude(dft_shift[:, :, 0], dft_shift[:, :, 1]) + 1)

    ## mean of each region of magnitude spectrum
    h_step, w_step, means = size // 3, size // 3, []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            region = magnitude_spectrum[i * h_step:(i + 1) * h_step, j * w_step:(j + 1) * w_step]
            means.append(np.mean(region))

    ## summarize redundant regions
    results = {
        "high_dia": np.mean([means[0], means[2], means[6], means[8]]),
        "high_ver": np.mean([means[1], means[7]]),
        "high_hor": np.mean([means[3], means[5]]),
        "low": means[4]
        }
    
    ## stats on the entire magnitude spectrum  
    mean_magnitude = np.mean(magnitude_spectrum)
    std_magnitude = np.std(magnitude_spectrum)
    high_freq_count = np.sum(magnitude_spectrum > (mean_magnitude + std_magnitude))
    complexity_index = high_freq_count / (size * size)
    results.update({
        'mean_magnitude': mean_magnitude,
        'std_magnitude': std_magnitude,
        'complexity_index': complexity_index,  
    })
    
    return results

    # e.g.:
    # {'high_dia': 142.00233,
    #  'high_ver': 151.46822,
    #  'high_hor': 157.74525,
    #  'low': 183.77997,
    #  'mean_magnitude': 152.24626,
    #  'std_magnitude': 20.03775,
    #  'complexity_index': 0.14060277777777777}


For real data, the Fourier transform will be conjugate symmetric, meaning all of the relevant information of the output can be fully described with half of the image - sliced any direction through the middle. The angle of the content relative to the horizontal axis indicates directionality of periodic data, so vertical stripes would have a peak in the high horizontal. If a zebra turns 90 degrees, those vertical stripes might look more horizontal, shifting the peaks to high vertical. Distance from the center indicates low vs. high frequencies relative to pixel size (stripes per pixel).

Complexity has been defined in a lot of ways. Knowing which way is best for your application is a very hard problem, and will likely be difficult to apply to a larger dataset unless you have very good control over your environment, including how targets are photographed (distance, orientation) and lighting configurations, for both training and testing datasets - assuming you are performing some type of classification.

thanks for these insights. my guess was that the ms is symmetric, so my clumsy solution was to average the different regions (see code above), but slicing is more efficient - will implement that. re. complexity: fortunately I have a very standardized dataset (photographed museum specimens), so I am not too worried about noise. still, calling it complexity idx was maybe not ideal...
